# std :: chrono Не пойму, как использовать

Tags: c++, c++11

Работаю над заданием по созданию игры "Танчики" (Battle city). И уже почти все готово, но не могу настроить скорость полета снарядов. Они у меня молниеносно проходят всю карту, пока не долетят до препятствия. Узнал про std :: chrono, но никак не пойму, как его использовать.

```
      void tanks :: fire() {
    bullet();
    if (map[bulletY - 3][bulletX] == ' ' && map[y - 1][x] == 'I') {
        bulletY -= 2;
        for (int i = bulletY; i > 0; i--) {
            time_t BulletTimeNow = time(NULL);
            map[bulletY + 1][bulletX] = ' ';
            bulletY -= 1;
            if (map[bulletY - 2][bulletX] != ' ') {
                map[bulletY][bulletX] = ' ';
            }
            else {
                map[bulletY][bulletX] = 'o';
                time_t BulletTimeOld = time(NULL);
                if ((BulletTimeNow - BulletTimeOld) < 50) continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: И что конкретно с нем непонятно?

Comment: Мне нужно запомнить время выстрела now() и потом проверять при каждой прорисовке пули разницу во времени с момента выстрела. И если результат не удовлетворительный, то чуть больше подождать до след. прорисовки. После сего действия надо записать новое время в now() и по кругу.
Именно как это сделать с подобным кодом я не понимаю.

Comment: Для подсчета интервала времени используйте GetTickCount функцию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы использовал не время, а скорость (`bulletSpeed = 0,052`) и в цикле к координатам снаряда прибавлял скорость, но если ты принципиально хочешь через время, то проще сделать через `time`

Что-то типа

```
time_t BulletTimeOld = time(NULL);
time_t BulletTimeNow = time(NULL);
if ((BulletTimeNow - BulletTimeOld) < 200) continue;
```

где 200 - это время в миллисекундах (0.2 сек), за которое снаряд пролетает одну клетку.

**UPD**

Я уже и написал, что вводишь переменную скорости, и с каждым тиком цикла меняешь координаты в зависимости от скорости. Раз у тебя текстовая игра, то нужно координаты хранить в `float`, а рисовать снаряд на округлённых координатах.

Не знаю, как у тебя устроена игра, но по хорошему, должен быть отдельный бесконечный цикл, в котором последовательно выполняются все действия (движение_танка->движение_снаряда->проверка_на_попадание и т.д.) после чего уходить в сон на необходимое время.

Через время реализовывать плохая идея, ибо если прошло, допустим 192мс, то при ограничении 200мс, эти 192мс просто не засчитается, будто снаряд просто застыл на это время.

**UPD2**
Попробуй так

```
time_t BulletTimeOld = time(NULL);
void tanks :: fire() {
    bullet();
    if (map[bulletY - 3][bulletX] == ' ' && map[y - 1][x] == 'I') {
        bulletY -= 2;
        for (int i = bulletY; i > 0; i--) {
            map[bulletY + 1][bulletX] = ' ';
            bulletY -= 1;
            if (map[bulletY - 2][bulletX] != ' ') {
                map[bulletY][bulletX] = ' ';
            }
            else {
                map[bulletY][bulletX] = 'o';
                time_t BulletTimeNow = time(NULL);
                if ((BulletTimeNow - BulletTimeOld) < 50) continue;
                else BulletTimeNow = = time(NULL);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну, лично я думал, что можно как-то заставить задерживаться с помощью Sleep(), но оно не сработало. Потом на просторах интернета нашел, что можно поиграться со временем и будет нормально работать. Так что, я был бы рад увидеть еще и вариант со скоростью, если вам не сложно, конечно, т.к. время не принципиально

Comment: @ДимаМиллер дополнил ответ. Разбирайся, я спать пойду

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: "и в цикле к координатам снаряда прибавлял скорость" - ни в коем случае. При такой реализации скорость игры будет ощутимо плавать в зависимости от железа.

Comment: @Croessmah для избежания такой ситуации я и написал про сон после каждого тика.

Comment: Ой я бы поостерегся применять именно `time`, поскольку обычно (откровенно говоря, иных вариантов просто не встречал несмотря на unspecified) она возвращает время в секундах, так что <200 будет ждать более 3 минут...

Comment: @Harry то, что возвращает время в секундах не проблема, можно результат поделить на 1000 и будут миллисекунды

Comment: @Виталий Я обновил код в вопросе, если не сложно, можете посмотреть, правильно ли я реализовал ваш совет, а то в программе ничего не изменилось

Comment: @ДимаМиллер дополнил

Comment: @Виталий, к моему сожалению, оно не помогло

Comment: @ДимаМиллер *то, что возвращает время в секундах не проблема, можно результат поделить на 1000 и будут миллисекунды* - это не просто 5 баллов, это все 50! Вы сделали мой день, спасибо!